# How to identify which emails were considered against salesforce email limits by analyzing email logs?

Tags: email

**Problem Statement:** Let's say your org hits email limit. Now in order to understand because which emails volume is increased, one can go and pull the email logs that includes all emails like

- Email sent to the salesforce users (which does not count against       limit)
- Emails sent to contact and Lead from salesforce classic UI manually
  (which does not count against limit)
- Emails sent via ApexCode to users (which does not count against
  limit)
- Emails sent via Apex Code to non salesforce users (counts against
  limit)
- Emails sent via lightning email composer to everyone including
  contact, lead (counts against limit)

**Things tried:** Went through the email logs, like different columns:

- Date Time
- Internal Message ID
- Mail Event
- Recipient
- Sender
- Remote Host
- Bytes Transferred
- Salesforce.com User
- Message ID Header
- Retry Count
- Seconds In Queue
- Delivery Stage
- Relay Address
- TLS_Cipher
- TLS_Verified

Only thing which helps a little bit is grouping the emails by sender and Recipient wise then you get the idea who is utilizing the most of the emails but does not help whether those are the emails that we should be concerned about since we don't know whether those emails are considered against the limit or not.

If you have any other way to approach to this problem let me know. Goal is to identify the emails which are getting considered for the email limit.